# Boxplot not displaying correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am facing an issue with boxplot, have following dataset

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdTdF.png)

Code I applied is as follow

boxplot(bxplot$food1~bxplot$groupss)
    
It only shows plot for one variable and I want to use other two variables as well food2 and food3. So that we will have 6 boxplots.

Hope I have explained my questions correctly.

Thanks

Comment: The example data is not reproducible (image won't help if someone wants to run it and see what happens). And, did you try bxplot$groupss = as.factor(bxplot$groupss)? It can be the case that group names are being considered as numbers instead of factor levels as they are numbers.

Comment: Hi Shakir, I am a  new learner and that is why I simply used boxplot and changed other code in which I was trying to use ggplot. Is there any chance you could please explain me how to add other two variables in the code so that I can get 6 boxplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Usman - hope this will be helpful. If you use `as.factor` for your variable `groupss`, you should get 6 boxplots as desired:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat.m <- melt(df, id.vars='groupss', measure.vars=c('food1','food2','food3'))

p <- ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=as.factor(groupss), y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot()
p
```

As suggested above, you can change your column `groupss` to a factor itself as follows:

```
dat.m$groupss <- as.factor(dat.m$groupss)
```

Instead of `reshape2`, I use the latest `tidyr` which has `pivot_longer` an alternative to `melt`. This would accomplish the same thing:

```
library(tidyr)

dat.m2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("food"), names_to = "food", values_to = "value")

p <- ggplot(dat.m2, aes(x=as.factor(groupss), y=value, color=food)) +
  geom_boxplot()
p
```

**Edit**: If you wish to have food1, food2, and food3 on the x-axis, and for each of those 3, have 2 boxplots for groups 1 and 2, you can do the following:

```
p <- ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=as.factor(groupss))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

or for the `pivot_longer` version:

```
p <- ggplot(dat.m2, aes(x=food, y=value, color=as.factor(groupss))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks a lot for the help. The above code is working and but categories are organised two groups. I want 3 categories representing each food such as food1 box plot for groups 1 (2 plots); food2 box plot (2 plots); food 3 (2plots).

Comment: My final question, now i have 9 plots on x-axis, could you please tell me how can I label them?

Comment: When you say "label them" - could you provide more details? Are you trying to change the labels on the axes (e.g., `variable` and `value`)? Or tick labels (e.g., `food1`)? Or legend info? If you can, maybe show a picture of what you're looking for? Also, this might look neater with `facet_wrap`.  See various examples here: https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/02/how-to-make-grouped-boxplots-with-ggplot2/

Comment: Hi Ben, Please see the following image in which on x-axis I have 3 labels egg1, dust1 and birch1 where I want 0,1,2,3....9 for each plot a number representing it.

Comment: Hi @Ben, for some reason I cannot copy past images in the textbox. Otherwise I was going to share the plot which could easily explain everything to you.

Comment: if need to change plots into one colour only, how to do that?

Comment: If you use `color` in your aesthetic, you can add `scale_color_manual` and use whatever colors you like. For example, `scale_color_manual(values = "#FFFFFF")` would color all of the boxplots black.